# Requisição AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, aplicação-web, xmlhttprequest

Estou começando com AngularJS e para estudar criei uma aplicação que vi na internet, porém quando vou usar o comando
"ng-include="'Footer.html'" dentro da div ele dá um erro no console.

angular.js:12578 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:Caminho Do Arquivo. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Já alterei as permissões da pasta para que tudo tivesse acesso e mesmo assim não funcionou.

Answer (score 2):

Você provavelmente está abrindo o arquivo html direto de uma pasta, usando o protocolo `file://`, e o Chrome não permite o uso do XMLHttpRequest para URLs deste tipo, por isso o erro.

O que você precisa é usar algum servidor http, existem diversos simples de usar, se estiver usando alguma IDE para desenvolver ela pode já ter suporte a algum, se pretende usar alguma linguagem de programação para o backend pode valer a pena usar o dele para fazer isso, por exemplo o IISExpress se for usar ASP.Net ou LAMP/WANP se for usar PHP.

Comment: Leonardo, eu não conheço nada de angular, se eu criar uma aplicação em .net mvc eu consigo trabalhar ele da mesma forma é isso ?

Comment: O Angular é usado para o Frontend, geralmente você vai precisar de alguma outra linguagem para o Backend, é bem comum usar a WebApi do ASP.Net para isso e nada impede que você tenha os dois no mesmo projeto para tirar proveito do IISExpress para poder testar o seu programa.